# Defining styles that provide nested, parameterized styles with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, pgfkeys

I want to draw different kinds of graphs which I want to define using styles. One particular graph has labelled nodes, and I want to be able to attach these labels using a custom key (`cn`).

The following document demonstrates this, the problem is, that the node labels specified using `cn` do not show up.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{RegionGraph}=[
  every node/.style={fill=blue!20},
  every edge/.style={draw,latex-},
  cn/.style={label={#1}}
]    

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[RegionGraph]
  \draw (0,0)   node[cn=1] (lr1) {$X_1$}
        ++(2,0) node[cn=0] (lr2) {$X_2$} edge (lr1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Where as, when I add the definition of the `cn`-style directly to the picture, like in the following code, the labels do show.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[RegionGraph,cn/.style={label={#1}}]
    ...
```

What am I doing wrong and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you nest the style definitions you need to double the number of `#` characters as when they get expanded they halve the numbers. So if you nest it in three levels it needs `####1` with four levels eight times etc. That's why labels don't appear because `#1` holds the argument for `RegionGraph` but you meant `cn`'s own argument at the time when it is defined.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{RegionGraph/.style={
  every node/.style={fill=blue!20},
  every edge/.style={draw,latex-},
  cn/.style={label={##1}}
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[RegionGraph]
  \draw (0,0)   node[cn=1] (lr1) {$X_1$}
        ++(2,0) node[cn=0] (lr2) {$X_2$} edge (lr1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, and also explains the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @ziggystar My pleasure

Answer (score 1):

Use `tikzset` instead of `tikzstyle`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  every node/.style={fill=blue!20},
  every edge/.style={draw,latex-},
  cn/.style={label={#1}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0)   node[cn=1] (lr1) {$X_1$}
        ++(2,0) node[cn=0] (lr2) {$X_2$} edge (lr1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But now every picture has these styles applied. I want the style to be only valid in pictures with style `RegionGraph`.

Comment: Use `tikzset` definition in only desired `tikzpicture`.

Comment: But then I have to define it each time anew. Basically I want that adding `RegionGraph` to a picture enables the use of `cn` on the nodes of the picture. But maybe I have to settle with enabling `cn` globally for all nodes.